# How to use ejabberd in android?

Tags: android, ejabberd, instant-messaging

I want to use jabberd in android app. I have installed ejabberd server but ejabberd client is not working. Which one is the best ejabberd client?

Answer (score 11):

ejabberd is strictly an XMPP / Jabber server implementation. There is no such thing as an "ejabberd client". To interface with ejabberd, one can use any XMPP / Jabber client. Examples include [Psi](http://psi-im.org/), [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/), and so on.

You seem to be a bit confused about the whole idea of XMPP / Jabber. If you have an interest in it, I highly recommend reading [XMPP: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521271) in order to fully understand the concepts behind it, how to leverage it, and even how to implement your own client. In the book they happen to use Python with [SleekXMPP](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/wiki) for their example implementations, but there are many libraries for many languages out there.

Here are a few decently comprehensive lists of [XMPP clients](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/) and [XMPP libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

**EDIT:** I skipped over the fact that you'll be using Android. You can either use [aSmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) for a native Android app or implement a webapp using JavaScript with [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/).

Answer (score 4):

> > Which one is the best ejabberd client?
>
> You meant:
>
> Which one is the best **XMPP** client?

I personnally believe that Xabber and Beem may be the best Android XMPP clients at the time of this writing, Jabiru and Yaxim follow, others are specific or uninteresting to me.

Comment: Do check out http://beem-project.com/ too